# Ubuntu 22.04 does not detects external display after NVIDIA driver installed

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, nvidia-optimus, external-monitor, amd-ryzen

I have a new configuration and I have several issues. It's an Optimus laptop with AMD iGPU and NVIDIA dGPU (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070). I try to setup a dual boot system. So one of my main problems is that my [Lenovo Legion 5](https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/Legion/Legion_5_15ACH6H?M=82JU013FHV) does not detects my monitor after I installed the latest NVIDIA v520 driver from the Ubuntu repo. Before the NVIDIA driver installation the system detected correctly both displays. The external is an LG 24GM79G-B and it's connected via HDMI. Same happens if I connect the monitor via USB-C with a converter or natively with a DP cable.

inxi-G shows:

$ inxi -G

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA104M [GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile / Max-Q] driver: nvidia
    v: 520.56.06
  Device-2: AMD Cezanne driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-3: Chicony Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa gpu: amdgpu
    resolution: 1920x1080~165Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD RENOIR (LLVM 13.0.1 DRM 3.42 5.15.0-52-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5
```

Windows 10 detects both displays.

**UPDATE:**

I just realised that there are now two NVIDIA driver branches(?)/versions available since v515. When I created my report I did not noticed this difference. I installed the **open kernel** version of v520 first. So recently my issue was related with that mostly. Meanwhile I installed the original closed version and with that the inputs working **IF** I set the GPU handling to `on-demand` or `nvidia`. With `intel` switch this driver also fails and there are no video signals on the outputs. So basically both driver versions affected but somehow the original is partially working at the moment.

**UPDATE #2:**

Things going wild after v525. The open kernel version does not send any signal. The closed version cause serious continuous lag on external display when the profile is set to `on-demand`. But when I set it to `nvidia` it works well. If this is the 21st century and the upcoming year is the year of Linux again then I should forget completely this platform.

Comment: What driver did you have before? Why did you change the driver if it was working?

Comment: As I said it's a new configuration and I try to setup it. It's a brand new machine. There was no NVIDIA driver installed before. This is the first time installation.

Comment: Are you sure that the 520 driver is the correct one?

Comment: Absolutely sure.

Comment: what does `inxi -G`say? And could you - just for a test - disable the amd GPU in your bios? And check if [this problem](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-22-04-does-not-detect-external-monitor/223864) applies

Comment: here's the output: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/SgsSjD2fXS/ then disabled the iGPU. nothing changed. please clarify the third advice.

Comment: You should paste that code into your question, not making a "screenshot". Your nvidia drivers have not been loaded: `Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa gpu: amdgpu resolution: 1920x1080~165Hz` I added the data into your question.

Comment: oh and how can i figure out what cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today after I updated from NVIDIA 515 to NVIDIA 525. My third display, which is the only one connected to the iGPU, stopped working.

The solution for me was to go to `/etc/X11` and execute

```
$ sudo rm xorg.conf
```

And reboot. Then the display connected to the iGPU started working again.

To choose the driver for your hardware I recommend executing in the terminal

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
```

And install the driver that has "recommended" near it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have Lenovo Legion too with GeForce RTX 2060 Mobile and I had the exact same problem. I first updated to `nvidia-driver-525-open` in the Software & Updates application on Ubuntu 22.04 under Additional Drivers.

What solved this issue of HDMI not being found is choosing the previous driver package NVIDIA driver `metapackage from nvidia-driver-515 (proprietary)`. With this package, everything worked after restarting the machine.

Also I cannot use the xorg Video Nouveuau gestures for switching between workspaces (worked before as three finger swipe on touchpad), so I had to keybind that from `Super + PgDn/PgUp)...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with `nvidia-driver-530-open` not detecting any external displays on a Thinkpad X1 extreme (GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile).

```
VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] [10de:1f91] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Lenovo TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] [17aa:229f]
```

Reverting the nvidia driver to the non-open variant of the same version, i.e. `nvidia-driver-530` works for me. I assume there are some issues or lacking features in the open kernel driver variants that break external displays for now.