# HDMI not working after update on Lenovo

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, 22.04, hdmi

I have a Lenovo Legion 7 16ACHg6 that for a week decided not to detect any external HDMIs nor other types of cables. It is a dual booted laptop with Windows 10 on another disk (disabled Secure Boot, Dynamic graphics).

---

### Software specs

```
$ uname -a
Linux Legion-7-16ACHg6 5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:54:14 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Whenever I connect an HDMI, USB-C or other type of monitor output there is not detected whatsoever.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1600, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 2560x1600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 215mm
   2560x1600     60.00*+
   1920x1200     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1440x900      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   640x480       60.00
```

The laptop is currently using recommended NVIDIA drivers v525
[image: drivers]

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000024DCsv000017AAsd00003A58bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GA104M [GeForce RTX 3080 Mobile / Max-Q 8GB/16GB]
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-open - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-515 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Also when I run `nvidia-smi` I get (I found [`nvidia-smi` “No devices were found”](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-no-devices-were-found-vmware-esxi-ubuntu-server-20-04-03-with-rtx3070/202904) on NVIDIA forum but couldn't understand if there were a solution other than try to update)

```
$ nvidia-smi
No devices were found
```

and examining the `dmesg` output

```
 $ dmesg
 kernel_gsp_ga102.c:164
[ 1171.051704] NVRM nvAssertFailedNoLog: Assertion failed: status == NV_OK @ kernel_gsp_ga102.c:235
[ 1171.051706] NVRM kgspInitRm_IMPL: cannot bootstrap riscv/gsp: 0xffff
[ 1171.051709] NVRM RmInitAdapter: Cannot initialize GSP firmware RM
[ 1171.052644] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x62:0xffff:1622)
[ 1171.053189] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 0
```

Status of the NVIDIA modules

```
$ lsmod | grep nv
nvidia_uvm           1388544  0
nvidia_drm             69632  0
nvidia_modeset       1363968  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia               5935104  5 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        311296  2 amdgpu,nvidia_drm
drm                   622592  15 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,nvidia,amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper,nvidia_drm,ttm
nvme                   49152  5
nvme_core             135168  8 nvme
```

File `/etc/default/grub` contents:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

---

### Hardware informations

Output of `lspci` when an HDMI and a USB-C are plugged

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104M [GeForce RTX 3080 Mobile / Max-Q 8GB/16GB] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Gold P31 SSD
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5405
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne (rev c5)
06:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
06:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
06:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
06:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
07:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
07:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
```

i.e.

```
$ lspci -v | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104M [GeForce RTX 3080 Mobile / Max-Q 8GB/16GB] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne (rev c5) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Running `inxi -G` gives (i think this could help)

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA104M [GeForce RTX 3080 Mobile / Max-Q 8GB/16GB]
    driver: nvidia v: 525.60.11
  Device-2: AMD Cezanne driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-3: Acer Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: ati,fbdev
    unloaded: modesetting,radeon,vesa gpu: nvidia,amdgpu resolution: 2560x1600
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 22.0.5
```

---

### What I tried

I have already tried [updating `ubuntu-drivers`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394283/hdmi-port-not-working-with-ubuntu)

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

I tried [re configuring `gdm3`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078539/hdmi-port-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04)

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

I tried [commenting out `options nvidia-drm modeset=1`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105332/external-monitor-not-working-ubuntu-nvidia) in `/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf` file and leaving Power mode. I am currently running on Balance mode.
[image]

---

#### A brief personal comment

Citing a [very similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438162/ubuntu-22-04-does-not-detects-external-display-after-nvidia-driver-installed) (and also looking at the amount of questions arising in this realm of NVIDIA-HDMIs-graphics-drivers-etc.)

Aside from these considerations, thanks, as always, to the community.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so apparently the solution was super easy, even though now I am asking myself some "why?".

I could solve the problem by switching from the recommended driver for NVIDIA graphics to the proprietary non-open,

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000024DCsv000017AAsd00003A58bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GA104M [GeForce RTX 3080 Mobile / Max-Q 8GB/16GB]
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-open - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-515 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-open - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

with the reference to the above output from `nvidia-driver-525-open - distro non-free recommended` to `nvidia-driver-525 - distro non-free`, or with the GUI, from the 1st one to the 2nd.

[image]

Then what `recommended` means? I sense this is a misleading recommendation, and I suggest to maybe give some informations about that choice, maybe explaining that with some notebooks one is recommended, and with another another one is.

Hope this helps.